# SQL from multiple tables without join

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have three tables in oracle contain data from today, yesterday and day before yesterday and there is a column name 'date' . I need to find the table name of the table which contains data from yesterday based on 'date' column. How do I query without join because I don't need to join

Comment: Please remove mysql tag.  Show sample table data, and expected output, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can union the tables together.

For example (assuming all datefield contains 12 PM):

```
SELECT tablename
FROM (
    SELECT 'TABLE1' tablename, datefield
    FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TABLE2' tablename, datefield
    FROM TABLE2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TABLE3' tablename, datefield
    FROM TABLE3)
WHERE datefield = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1);
```

If all datefields are not 12 PM, then adjust to use BETWEEN for specific time.

For very large tables, move the WHERE statement into each table UNION.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the table name and you know there is one:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table1 where datefield = trunc(sysdate - 1))
             then 'table1'
             when exists (select 1 from table2 where datefield = trunc(sysdate - 1))
             then 'table2'
             when exists (select 1 from table3 where datefield = trunc(sysdate - 1))
             then 'table3'
        end) as whichtable
from dual;
```

This returns the first table that meets your condition.